# show Quests in the Google Play Quest list

Tags: android, google-play-games

Hey I have download the events and quest sample for android.
The events works nice but by the Quests are only the Quests list without the Quests. I have searched on how I can bring a Quest on the Quest list, but I have nothing found. I hope you can help me on how to make this

Answer (score 0):

If the list is empty, did you define a quest?

Quests are defined on the server side independent of the game application so you can create quests without having to republish your game.

The detailed instructions for creating a quest are at https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/quests#quest_basics.

In summary:

1. In the Google Play Developer Console, click on the Game services icon on the left and select the entry for your game.
2. Select the Quests tab on the left, and click on the Add quest button. 
   (You must create an event first, if you have not already done so.)
3. Fill in the details for the quest you want to create.
4. Click Save. If there are no errors, the Google Play Developer Console displays a Publish Quest button. However, before you proceed to publish your quest, make sure to test your game to verify the new quest.